# Google+ Sign-In button custom image

Tags: google-plus

I've implemented Sign-In using Google's tutorials, but the button doesn't really fit in with the design of the website I'm using it in. I'd like to use an image my graphic designer made instead. Is it currently possible to use a custom image for Sign-In buttons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [gapi.signin.render](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#javascript_api) to render a specified container as a sign-in button.
For example if in your HTML code you have:

`<button id="mySignIn">SignIn</button>`

The Javascript call would be something like:

```
gapi.signin.render("mySignIn", { 
  'callback': signinCallback, 
  'clientid': 'CLIENT_ID', 
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin', 
  'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
});
```

Also, remember to follow the [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines).

Comment: Ah, it appears that there was more button choice than I knew about. Thanks for solving both the question AND the design problem.

Comment: I believe the newer version of this api call would be `gapi.signin2.render`

Comment: This link may help: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#customizing_the_automatically_rendered_sign-in_button_recommended

Answer (score -3):

The following code is used to add the login button to the page right?

```
<span id="signinButton">  
   <span 
      class="g-signin" 
      data-callback="signinCallback" 
      data-clientid="CLIENT_ID" 
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" 
      data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" 
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">  
   </span>
</span>
```

Have you tried to simply replace the class "g-signin" with your own class??

If g-signin is required for google themselves, to determine which is the actual signin button, you could always add a subclass to it.

```
<span class="g-signin custom" ...></span>
```

In your CSS this would be shown as:

```
.g-signin .custom {
/*properties*/
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and get back with the result later today. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: This approach won't work to customize the button. The Google scripts transforms the element and creates iframes when done this way and you won't be able to style that button. You'll want to use Silvano's answer to be able to fully customize the button.